# Xcode throwing 64-bit errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6.1

I am having trouble building my iOS app since probably last Thursday, February 12. I use DCIntrospect as an imported library using CocoaPods, and when I build the app (Standard Architectures + armv7s) the build fails over a `DEBUGGER` instruction in DCIntrospect, giving me the error message

> Instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode

I reverted my changes to a stable build to make sure it wasn't an issue with the code, and I still get the same build failures. Has anyone else experienced this issue within the past week or so?

**Edit:**

I've since been able to get around the failure with DCIntrospect, but I'm now receiving linker errors due to the KIF library:

```
Ld /Users/mcampo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beam-ehqrhnpimyxzdkgifcnxicyobbgo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beamTests.octest/beamTests normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/mcampo/Documents/Web Apps/beam"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/mcampo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beam-ehqrhnpimyxzdkgifcnxicyobbgo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/mcampo/Documents/Web\ Apps/beam/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/mcampo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beam-ehqrhnpimyxzdkgifcnxicyobbgo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/mcampo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beam-ehqrhnpimyxzdkgifcnxicyobbgo/Build/Intermediates/beam.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/beamTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/beamTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/mcampo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beam-ehqrhnpimyxzdkgifcnxicyobbgo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beam.app/beam -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-beamTests-AFNetworking -lPods-beamTests-DCIntrospect-ARC -lPods-beamTests-Expecta -lPods-beamTests-KIF -lPods-beamTests-KIFViewControllerActions -lPods-beamTests-Kiwi -lPods-beamTests-OCMock -lPods-beamTests-RKKiwiMatchers -lPods-beamTests-RestKit -lPods-beamTests-SOCKit -lPods-beamTests-TransitionKit -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SenTestingKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -lPods-beamTests-KIF -lPods-beamTests-KIFViewControllerActions -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods-beamTests -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mcampo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beam-ehqrhnpimyxzdkgifcnxicyobbgo/Build/Intermediates/beam.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/beamTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/beamTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mcampo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beam-ehqrhnpimyxzdkgifcnxicyobbgo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beamTests.octest/beamTests

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mcampo/Documents/Web Apps/beam/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._locationInWindow", referenced from:
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) initAtPoint:inWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) setLocationInWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._phase", referenced from:
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) initAtPoint:inWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) setPhase:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._previousLocationInWindow", referenced from:
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) initAtPoint:inWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) setLocationInWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._tapCount", referenced from:
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) initAtPoint:inWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._timestamp", referenced from:
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) initAtPoint:inWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) setPhase:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) setLocationInWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._touchFlags", referenced from:
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) initAtPoint:inWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._view", referenced from:
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) initAtPoint:inWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._window", referenced from:
      -[UITouch(KIFAdditions) initAtPoint:inWindow:] in libPods-beamTests-KIF.a(UITouch-KIFAdditions.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please note: these issues ***were not*** occurring until February 12, and the build was stable until then. Rolling back did ***nothing*** to fix this error.

Comment: Do you have done a clean  after your reverted the changes to a stable build ?

Comment: @samir I've tried cleaning, I've tried deep cleaning, I've uninstalled and re-installed Xcode, I've tried everything under the sun.

Comment: @matt I mentioned I rolled back my code to a version that I had previously successfully built. This isn't an issue with any of my libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the build settings are local." They're stored in a file which is version controlled. This sounds like it could be something that would normally cause these issues, but I can't imagine that I won't be able to pull down build settings from git.

Comment: If it was working before a certain date and if the changes were under version control, rolling back to before that date would fix everything. But you say it doesn't. Therefore whatever changed is something you changed on your machine and it is not under version control.

Comment: Maybe what you changed is a Scheme. _Those_ are certainly not under version control on my machine. - But the point is, you need to think about YOU. _You_ changed something. The universe did not miraculously go wrong on February 12.

Comment: You might be on to something there. I'm not familiar with schemes and how to change them, but I'll check and see if my teammate's is different.